# Refer to Function name via passed varaible

Tags: vba, excel

This line:

```
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Module2.FirstBBSName)
```

will set the worksheet as the name of the return from the function, which will be the name of a sheet.

However, in this sub, this will need to change to:

```
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Module2.SecondBBSName)
```

or

```
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Module2.ThirdBBSName)
```

and so on. I need to do this by passing the name from a `call` via a variable. Lets name it `SheetNameReturn`.

So if I send:

```
Call NameOfMySub ("SecondBBSName")
```

It will then not work if I use

```
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Module2.SheetNameReturn)
```

As obviously it is looking for `SheetNameReturn` in Module2 and not the variable.

What do I need to do to make it look at the passed variable instead?

Comment: Hard to see what you want to achieve, use a function and pass an argument? - `Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Module2.GenerateNameByNumber(3))`

Comment: the `FirstBBSName` (and SecondBBSName, and ThirdBBSName)function gives the name of the Nth sheet, this is used elsewhere in the workbook, but here I need to get that same Nth sheet name to set it as the sheet name for this `ws`. I cannot specify a number for the sheet as it is not going to be the same every time.

Comment: The function used (FirstBBSName, SecondBBSName, ThirdBBSName) is going to be different each time I call the sub, which is why I wanted to pass it through in the `SheetNameReturn` variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a function named by a variable with [`Application.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197132.aspx).

See the code below - `strFunction` (could be `SheetNameReturn`) takes the name of the function (optionally with module prefix) and you then pass that string to `Run` to call the function.

**Module1:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strFunction As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    strFunction = "Module2.FirstBBSName"
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Application.Run(strFunction))
    Debug.Print ws.Name

    strFunction = "Module2.SecondBBSName"
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Application.Run(strFunction))
    Debug.Print ws.Name

    strFunction = "Module2.ThirdBBSName"
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Application.Run(strFunction))
    Debug.Print ws.Name

End Sub
```

**Module2:**

```
Option Explicit

Function FirstBBSName()
    FirstBBSName = "Sheet1"
End Function
Function SecondBBSName()
    SecondBBSName = "Sheet2"
End Function
Function ThirdBBSName()
    ThirdBBSName = "Sheet3"
End Function
```